Update table content on selecting tabs
I have a table that the content need to be filtered by status tabs ('new', 'on process', 'delivered', etc) usually i'm using useEffect to catch this status tabs selection, and useState to update the table data, but now i have issues where the state is updating (by logging the 'tableData' content just after i call setTableData) but the table still on previous 'tableData' state.. can you guys tell me where is the problem?
export const OrdersTab = (tabsData : any) => {
// console.log(tabsData);
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] : any = useState(null);
const [activeStatusTab, setActiveStatusTab] : any = useState();
const [tableData, setTableData]:any[] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

// console.log(tabsData);

useEffect(() => {
    
        if (activeStatusTab) {
            let filteredOrderes = tabsData.initTableData;
            // console.log(filteredOrderes);
            if (activeStatusTab == 'all') {
                filteredOrderes = tabsData.initTableData;
            } else {
                filteredOrderes = filteredOrderes.filter((orders:any) => 
                    orders.status.toString().toLowerCase().includes(activeStatusTab.toLowerCase())
                );
            }
            // console.log(filteredOrderes.length);
            setTableData(filteredOrderes);
            console.log(tableData.length); /* <<-- checking if state updating/not */
        }
}, [activeStatusTab]);

let statusTabs = [
    {
      id: "all",
      label: "All"
    },
    {
      id: "new",
      label: "New"
    },
    {
      id: "process",
      label: "On Process"
    },
    {
      id: "delivery",
      label: "Delivery"
    },
    {
      id: "completed",
      label: "Completed"
    },
    {
      id: "canceled",
      label: "Canceled"
    },
    {
      id: "failed",
      label: "Failed"
    },
];
return (
    <Card>
        <CardBody>
            <div className="flex w-full flex-col">
                <Tabs aria-label="Dynamic tabs" 
                    onSelectionChange={(tabKey) => setActiveTab(tabKey)}
                    fullWidth={true} 
                    items={tabsData.tabsData} >
                    {(item:any) => (
                    <Tab key={item.id} title={item.name}>
                        <Tabs aria-label="Options" onSelectionChange={(statusKey) => setActiveStatusTab(statusKey)} fullWidth={true} items={statusTabs}>
                            {(item) => (
                            <Tab key={item.id} title={item.label}>
                                    <Table id="tablexxx" aria-label="Example empty table">
                                        <TableHeader>
                                            <TableColumn>Product(s)</TableColumn>
                                            <TableColumn>Date</TableColumn>
                                            <TableColumn>Store</TableColumn>
                                            <TableColumn>Status</TableColumn>
                                            <TableColumn>Total Amount</TableColumn>
                                            <TableColumn>Courier</TableColumn>
                                            <TableColumn>Action</TableColumn>
                                        </TableHeader>
                                        {(tableData.length > 0) ? (
                                            <TableBody>
                                                {tableData.map((item:any) => (
                                                    <TableRow key={item.invoice}>
                                                        <TableCell>
                                                            <Link href={'/orders/' + item.id}>
                                                                {item.products[0].main_product.name}
                                                                <p className="text-default-400">SKU: {item.products[0].main_product.sku} x {item.products[0].qty}</p>
                                                                <p className="text-default-400">Invoice: {item.invoice}</p>
                                                            </Link>
                                                        </TableCell>
                                                        <TableCell>{item.createdAt.split('T')[0]}</TableCell>
                                                        <TableCell>{item.store.name}</TableCell>
                                                        <TableCell>{item.status}</TableCell>
                                                        <TableCell>{item.total_amount}</TableCell>
                                                        <TableCell>{item.logistic.name}</TableCell>
                                                        <TableCell>
                                                            {<Dropdown>
                                                                <DropdownTrigger>
                                                                    <Button 
                                                                    variant="bordered"
                                                                    isIconOnly  
                                                                    >
                                                                        <svg className="bi bi-three-dots-vertical" fill="currentColor" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M9.5 13a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0zm0-5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0zm0-5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0z"/></svg>
                                                                    </Button>
                                                                </DropdownTrigger>
                                                                <DropdownMenu aria-label="Static Actions">
                                                                    <DropdownItem key="new">View</DropdownItem>
                                                                    <DropdownItem key="copy"><Link href={"/orders/" + item.id}>Process</Link></DropdownItem>
                                                                    <DropdownItem key="delete" className="text-danger" color="danger">
                                                                    Reject
                                                                    </DropdownItem>
                                                                </DropdownMenu>
                                                            </Dropdown>}
                                                        </TableCell>
                                                    </TableRow>
                                                ))}
                                            </TableBody>
                                        ) : (
                                            <TableBody emptyContent={"No rows to display."}>{[]}</TableBody>
                                        )} 
                                        
                                    </Table>
                            </Tab>
                            )}
                        </Tabs>
                    </Tab>
                    )}
                    
                </Tabs>
            </div>  
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
)}


nevermind, i already fixed this issue.. if anyone has same problem, comment here if you need my solutions

Issue: setTableData(filteredOrderes) is called, but React updates the state asynchronously. So, console.log(tableData.length) right after setTableData is still showing the old value of tableData since the state update hasn't been applied yet.
Fix:

Remove the console.log(tableData.length) from directly after setTableData.
Add a separate useEffect that runs when tableData changes and log its value there.



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const OrdersTab = (tabsData: any) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(null);
  const [activeStatusTab, setActiveStatusTab] = useState();
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  // Effect to filter table data based on selected status tab
  useEffect(() => {
    if (activeStatusTab) {
      let filteredOrders = tabsData.initTableData;
      
      if (activeStatusTab === 'all') {
        filteredOrders = tabsData.initTableData;
      } else {
        filteredOrders = filteredOrders.filter((orders: any) => 
          orders.status.toString().toLowerCase().includes(activeStatusTab.toLowerCase())
        );
      }

      // Update tableData state with filtered orders
      setTableData(filteredOrders);
    }
  }, [activeStatusTab, tabsData.initTableData]);

  // Effect to log the updated tableData when it changes
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Updated tableData length:', tableData.length);
  }, [tableData]); // This effect runs whenever tableData is updated

  let statusTabs = [
    { id: "all", label: "All" },
    { id: "new", label: "New" },
    { id: "process", label: "On Process" },
    { id: "delivery", label: "Delivery" },
    { id: "completed", label: "Completed" },
    { id: "canceled", label: "Canceled" },
    { id: "failed", label: "Failed" },
  ];

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardBody>
        <div className="flex w-full flex-col">
          <Tabs
            aria-label="Dynamic tabs"
            onSelectionChange={(tabKey) => setActiveTab(tabKey)}
            fullWidth={true}
            items={tabsData.tabsData}
          >
            {(item: any) => (
              <Tab key={item.id} title={item.name}>
                <Tabs
                  aria-label="Options"
                  onSelectionChange={(statusKey) => setActiveStatusTab(statusKey)}
                  fullWidth={true}
                  items={statusTabs}
                >
                  {(item) => (
                    <Tab key={item.id} title={item.label}>
                      <Table id="tablexxx" aria-label="Example empty table">
                        <TableHeader>
                          <TableColumn>Product(s)</TableColumn>
                          <TableColumn>Date</TableColumn>
                          <TableColumn>Store</TableColumn>
                          <TableColumn>Status</TableColumn>
                          <TableColumn>Total Amount</TableColumn>
                          <TableColumn>Courier</TableColumn>
                          <TableColumn>Action</TableColumn>
                        </TableHeader>
                        {tableData.length > 0 ? (
                          <TableBody>
                            {tableData.map((item: any) => (
                              <TableRow key={item.invoice}>
                                <TableCell>
                                  <Link href={'/orders/' + item.id}>
                                    {item.products[0].main_product.name}
                                    <p className="text-default-400">
                                      SKU: {item.products[0].main_product.sku} x {item.products[0].qty}
                                    </p>
                                    <p className="text-default-400">Invoice: {item.invoice}</p>
                                  </Link>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{item.createdAt.split('T')[0]}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{item.store.name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{item.status}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{item.total_amount}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{item.logistic.name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                  <Dropdown>
                                    <DropdownTrigger>
                                      <Button variant="bordered" isIconOnly>
                                        <svg
                                          className="bi bi-three-dots-vertical"
                                          fill="currentColor"
                                          height="16"
                                          viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                                          width="16"
                                          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        >
                                          <path d="M9.5 13a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0zm0-5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0zm0-5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0z" />
                                        </svg>
                                      </Button>
                                    </DropdownTrigger>
                                    <DropdownMenu aria-label="Static Actions">
                                      <DropdownItem key="new">View</DropdownItem>
                                      <DropdownItem key="copy">
                                        <Link href={"/orders/" + item.id}>Process</Link>
                                      </DropdownItem>
                                      <DropdownItem key="delete" className="text-danger" color="danger">
                                        Reject
                                      </DropdownItem>
                                    </DropdownMenu>
                                  </Dropdown>
                                </TableCell>
                              </TableRow>
                            ))}
                          </TableBody>
                        ) : (
                          <TableBody emptyContent={"No rows to display."}>{[]}</TableBody>
                        )}
                      </Table>
                    </Tab>
                  )}
                </Tabs>
              </Tab>
            )}
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};



